# Combo detection mechanism

Tags: algorithm

In a Point of Sale system, the cashier keys in the product type and the quantity one by one. Suppose there is a business rule for combos, for example buy 2 fries with 2 cokes and you get $1 off. I want to create a mechanism that automatically detect combos in the list of products bought, and then apply the appropriate discount.

The product master contains around 4000 items. There will be around 100 combos. Average number of products bought in a transaction is 2. Up to now the highest number of products in a transaction ever recorded is 128.

My thinking is if there are 3 products (A, B, C) in a transaction, I have to check the presence of combo for (A, B), (A, C), (B, C), (A, B, C). The number of combinations that need to be checked rise pretty fast when the transaction has more product types.

Is this possible? Anybody ever tried something like this? Care to share some insight on how to implement this?

Platform is vb.net 2010 and SQL Server 2005.

EDIT

A combo will contain 2 to 4 items.

Comment: What is the min. and max number of items in combo ?
Is it 1 to 128 ?

Comment: @Ajeet a combo will contain 2 to 4 items.

Comment: Do all combos provide the same savings or are some combos better than others?  You gave the example of 2 fries plus 2 cokes = $1 discount.  Is it possible to have a combo of 1 sandwich plus 1 fry plus 1 coke = $1.5 discount?  Should the algorithm automatically give the best possible result?  If so, then this sounds like a job for the greedy algorithm as applied to the knapsack problem.

Comment: You'd need to elaborate more. Can combos overlap? If Combo1 2A2B=-$1 and Combo2 2B2C=-$2 and I buy 2A2B2C do I save $3 or $2?

Comment: @oosterwal possible to have the same product in several combos. Yes the algo has to give the biggest discount. Will you post answer? Would love to know how to use knapsack in this case.

Comment: @lastcoder 2b2c give the biggest discount, so $2, and then the 2b2c got taken out of the list, and detection proceed on the rest of the list.

Comment: @Endy Tjahjono:  To view this as the knapsack problem, consider the total order to be the knapsack, and the combo-discounts as the items to be fit into the knapsack.  You want to fit the largest possible sum of discounts into your order.

Answer (score 1):

You could sort your possible combos like you already did in your post, then create a tree structure. 
If you have to check a combo, you first look for the first item (e.g. A), then follow the tree, then check for the next item (e.g. C). If you can find this, there is a possible combination, else not.

Different solution:
Save all combinations sorted as in your question in a hash map and then look those combinations up. I could imagine this as pretty fast, but it would need a lot of space and some time to generate the hash map.

Comment: this solution will not handle the variable 'quantity' associated with item in combo.  2-coke is diff from 4-coke.

Comment: You could remove the found items from the rest, then you would find again 2-coke-combo. But you are right, it does not work if you have many items and want to find as many combos as possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
// I figured it is easy to post code than explaining long-winded style. All are programmer here anyways
typedef pair<string,int> item_quant;
bool funccomp (const item_quant& lhs, const item_quant& rhs)
{
    if((lhs.first < rhs.first) ||  (lhs.second < rhs.second))
        return true;
    return false;
}
struct classcomp {
    bool operator() (const vector<item_quant>& lhs, const vector<item_quant>& rhs) const
    {
        if(lhs.size() < rhs.size())
            return true;
        for(unsigned int i=0; i< lhs.size();++i)
        {
            if(!funccomp(lhs[i],rhs[i]))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
} classcompObj;



int main()
{
    // Insert
    map<vector<item_quant>,int,classcomp> table;
    vector<item_quant> v;
    v.push_back(make_pair("coke",2));
    v.push_back(make_pair("fries",2));
    // Dont forget to sort.
    sort(v.begin(),v.end(),funccomp) ;
    table[v] = 1;

    //search
    int disc = (*table.find(v)).second;
    cout<<" disc = "<<disc<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have to refresh my c++ comprehension first, but thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok, so here is the Aglo translation :
Think of each Combination as list. Elements within lists are sorted, making list comparable.
You have a hash map of these lists.

To add a new Comb. create a new list and add it to Hash-map.
To search, simply recreate list and search in hash-map.

Comment: Also one more thing. A custom  Trie data structure is perfectly suited for your task.  Each node in trie is  ItemName+Number.